# Edge is serving API from cache even after passing cache-control and pragma headers

Tags: vue.js, axios, microsoft-edge, asp.net-core-webapi, cache-control

API is being fetched from cache. This is happening only in Edge. I went through many similar questions in stackoverflow and tried everything but in vain.

I added cache related headers in Vue js

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Cache-Control'] = 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Expires'] = 0
axios.defaults.headers.common['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
axios.defaults.headers.common['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'
```

I also added cache headers from server side.

```
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None)]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(AuthenticateFilter))]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("{tenant}")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
}
```

My Request headers looks like in chrome

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Token ggggggggggggggggggggg
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: 0
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Origin: http://somedummy.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://somedummy.com/dashboard/sample
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
withCredentials: true
```

And response headers :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://somedummy.com
Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2019 08:35:36 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-StackifyID: V1|b6841c38-3ec0-4a46-ac24-699ac8a5af0d|
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

APIs are being fetched from server in IE, chrome and safari but only in Edge it is being served from cache even though "Always refresh from server" option in developer option is selected.

[image]

I also have added meta in index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

There are no errors in console. No preflight (OPTIONS) call going from Edge. Strange thing is when fiddler is open then APIs are being served from server in Edge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Cache headers are *response headers*. Adding them client-side with your requests is doing absolute nothing. 2) The headers only have an effect if they were set *before* the resources were cached. As such, have you tried clearing the cache in Edge to force it to pull down the resources anew? 3) Meta tags only affect the HTML document itself, not resources delivered via it. As a result, that does nothing either.

Comment: Yes, I had cleared the cache in Edge but still browser forces API to read from cache

Comment: What's the Edge version? Have you ever changed the Edge setting, if you changed the setting, try to [reset the Edge setting](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10).

Comment: I have not changed the Edge settings. Version -  Microsoft Edge 41.16299.820.0 , Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299

Answer (score 1):

Your modification is a **Server Response**, this won't work, instead you should use   `headers: { Pragma: 'no-cache' }`

Example:

```
const api = axios.create({
  headers: { Pragma: 'no-cache' },
});
```

Or add it to the configuration

```
const config = {
    headers: { Pragma: 'no-cache'},
    params: { id: this.state.taskID }
}
axios.get("some URL", config).then(...)
```